# rails fields_for array of number_field must be of different values

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, distinct, form-for, multiple-records

I'm working on a ruby on rails app, where I have a model called categories with a field called "order_point", even though the "order_point" field shouldn't be of unique (different) value per record,

I want to create a form where I update multiple records's order_point attribute, and I want to make the form accept only the entered values of order_point, only if the the values are different ...

for example:
I have categories A, B, and C, I want to create a form to input and update categories A,B,C at once, but if the entered order_point values of any of the 3 categories are the same, then the form should not submit (for example A= 3, B= 2, c=2).

I created the form the could update multiple records values at once using f.number_field which is nested in fields_for, here's my code:

```
<section class="container page-container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Arabic Name</th>
        <th>Order Strength</th>
        <th colspan="3"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <%= form_tag admin_category_submit_order_categories_path, method: :post do %>
        <% @categories.each do |category| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= category.name %></td>
            <td><%= category.ar_name %></td>
            <td>
              <%= fields_for "categories[]", category do |f|%>
                <%= f.number_field :order_point, value: category.order_point, in: 1...@categories.count+1 %>
              <% end %>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>

        <div class="col-md-12">
          <%= submit_tag("Update", { class: "btn btn-primary pull-right"}) %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

and here's a screenshot:

[image]

knowing that order strength is the order_point attribute

any solutions?

Comment: "I want to create a form to input and update categories A,B,C at once, but if the entered order_point values of any of the 3 categories are the same, then the form should not submit". If you want to prevent the form from submitting you need to use javascript to attach a event listener to the submit event. As to the rest of the question - I have read it two times and still don't really get what you are trying to do. Could you give a brief outline of the user story? I get a feeling that what you may be looking for is your average drag & drop reordering setup.

Comment: exactly, I want to store those values for re-ordering the categories records, so I want to give each category a unique value on the order_point attribute, where the range is from 1 to the number of categories, this shouldn't be applied to all categories but categories of specific type, so the uniqueness validation can't be applied to the category model, so there are 3 solutions
1. add an event listener (a solution involve JS which I don't prefer)                                       2. check if the submitted array of values is unique, if so then update, otherwise then send user to edit page

Comment: 3. some kind of validation on the level of the form_for or the f.field_number which make sure that all the field_number inputs inside the form_for are different, which I'm searching for, this would be the easiest solution if there's some validator like that

Comment: There is no ready made solution here. Usually this kind of thing is done by wrapping the objects in another model and using `accepts_nested_attributes`. I would setup a virtual model (a class that includes the `ActiveModel::Model` module) and bind the form and incoming params to that model and add a custom validation. This would be way to long and require way to much effort for a stackoverflow answer though but at least you have a starting point for your research.